# Hive - static partitioning - difference between creating the partition directory directly vs using alter table statement

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, hive-partitions, hiveddl

Are there any internal/performance difference between the below two statements for creating static partitioning in hive, I have tried both ways and both of them are working without any issues after loading the data into partition

```
dfs -mkdir /user/cloudera/sqoop_import/avroData/orders_part/order_month=2014-02;
alter table orders_part add partition(order_month='2014-02');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command:   `dfs -mkdir /user/cloudera/sqoop_import/avroData/orders_part/order_month=2014-02;` does not create partition, it creates a directory. This directory is not mounted as a table partition yet. Partition is a directory plus a metadata containing information about partition (key value+partition directory) stored in metastore. You can check it easily using `show partitions orders_part;` command after executing mkdir. This directory will not be in the partitions list.

`alter table orders_part add partition(order_month='2014-02');` Creates a directory `order_month=2014-02` and mounts it as a partition.

Partitions can be created dynamically using

```
insert overwrite table orders_part partition(order_month) 
select ...
```

command. In this case directories will be created automatically and mounted as partitions.

Consider this: You can make a partition not necessarily located in directory equal to 'key=value'. For example: `alter table orders_part add partition(order_month='2014-02') location '/user/cloudera/sqoop_import/avroData/orders_part/mydir' ;` Note the partition directory is now `'/user/cloudera/sqoop_import/avroData/orders_part/mydir'`.

Comment: Thank you @leftjoin , this is helpful. 'show partitions oders_part' is showing both the partitions, Iam using cloudera quickstart vm 5.7.0

Comment: It probably left from your previous table load. drop partition first (alter table drop partition) then mkdir then show partitions. mkdir should not create partition.

Comment: I have created two partitions, one with `alter table` and another one by directly creating the directory, when I did  `show partitions orders_part` only the one created using `alter table` showed up, but after loading data into the partitions, both were displayed when  I did `show partitions orders_part`

Comment: Yes, it's because second partition was created dynamically during load.  It's impossible to create partition by creating directory. It's possible to create partitions by issuing 'alter table add partition' or loading data and creating them dynamically. And you did so - created partition dynamically during loading data.

Comment: But you are still not satisfied with my explanation? So please suggest wat is wrong and how I can improve my answer